# IPSConfig3 permissions problem for FTP users

Tags: permissions, ftp

I am using ISPConfig3 for creating **websites** and **FTP users** as well.

When I create an FTP user, he is under **Client 1** user. But website is under **www-data** user.

This creates struggle, if an owner of a website is Client 1, then FTP users can write files / edit files in FTP, but website can not access some of it's contents which results in permission denied logs.

If an owner is www-data, then FTP users can not even see the files, nor edit them.

I am using those commands to switch between the permissions as needed but I would like to somehow make both - so FTP users can edit files and website can access it's files.

I am using this to grant permissions to FTP users:

```
chown -R web5:client1 /var/www/clients/client1/web5/web
```

And this to retrieve it back to website:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/clients/client1/web5/web
```

How can I achieve both? I tried adding web5 user to user group but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep them owned by `www-data:www-data`
2. Add `web5` user to `www-data` group
3. Set permissions to allow group read/write `chmod g+rw ...` or `664`

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a shell user from ISPConfig panel, you can connect to the server through SFTP using the shell-user credentials.
To create shell-user, do the followings:
a) Go to **Sites** tab
b) Click on **Shell-user** on sidebar.
c) Select a specific website and create it.